# Need error free test for existence of environment variable

Tags: bash

I have a situation where it is normal for an environment variable to be set or not, In my script i want to detect if the variable is set.  Any suggestions as to how to handle this?

'''${x?}''' does the job but generates a bash error.

Comment: `echo "${x-message}"` produces `message` if `x` is unset, otherwise the content of `$x` (even if that was set to the empty string). Alternatively, replace `-` with `+` to produce the message iff the variable *was* set.

Comment: @pmf That does the job, thank you. If you make it into an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Examples using [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) `${parameter-word}` and `${parameter+word}`:

```bash
unset x; echo "${x-is not set}"   # prints: is not set
x=content; echo "${x-is not set}" # prints: content
x=""; echo "${x-is not set}"      # prints the empty string

unset x; echo "${x+is set}"       # prints the empty string
x=content; echo "${x+is set}"     # prints: is set
x=""; echo "${x+is set}"          # prints: is set
```